# Upgraded Outlook to 64 bit and VBA code no longer works

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, 64-bit

I upgraded my Outlook applications from 32 bit to 64 bit and the VBA code I use to save attachments no longer runs and I can't figure out why. I am on windows 10 and office 365

```
Public Sub Enable(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If itm.Subject = "Terminal 2 Enable Ops Logs" Then
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    FName = (objAtt.FileName)
    T2Log = "D:\Data\Enable\Ops Logs\Terminal 2\"

        If fso.FileExists(T2Log & FName) Then
        Kill T2Log & FName
        End If

    objAtt.SaveAsFile T2Log & FName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next

ElseIf itm.Subject = "Terminal 3 IB Enable Ops Logs" Then
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    FName = (objAtt.FileName)
    T3IBLog = "D:\Data\Enable\Ops Logs\Terminal 3\"

        If fso.FileExists(T3IBLog & FName) Then
        Kill T3IBLog & FName
        End If

    objAtt.SaveAsFile T3IBLog & FName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

The rule still run when the emails arrive and i don't get any error messages but the file is not saved to the location.

Comment: Use the `VBA Debugger` to isolate the problem. Why do you change the loop variable `objAtt` at the end of the `for each` loop? In general, I put `option explicit` on top of my VBA sources and explicitely declare all my used variables.

Comment: @AxelKemper Thanks for replying. I found the problem is was this line in another module `'Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)` changed it to `Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)` and now its working.

Comment: @AxelKemper can you explain what you meant by "Why do you change the loop variable objAtt at the end of the for each loop?" I am not an expert so any help will be appreciated. do you mean where i set the file path T2Log and T3IBLog ? Thanks

Comment: `Set objAtt = Nothing` as last statement of the `for each` loop is changing the loop variable. Usually, such a variable should be treated as read-only.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you need to review all external function declarations such as Windows API calls. The Outlook object model is the same on both platforms.